# Loop through time difference logic

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using Joda DateTime and have 2 dates :

```
DateTime old //which is 1:46PM   
DateTime new //which is 6:46PM
```

note: excluded the dates.

How may i be able to loop through the difference in this order :

(print a message for the first half hour, another message for the next 30 minutes and another message per subsequent hour) ?

I was thinking of Subtracting the old date from the new date then make a loop but i don't get the logic. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
example
If i subtract both times above, i will have an elapsed time of 5 hours.

Loop 5 hours
{
   for the first hour (print this)
   next 30minutes (print that)
   every subsequent hour (print ....)
}
```

Comment: it's not very clear what you want to accomplish, could you please add an example with two real dates and would should the output be?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy please check the updated

Comment: Imagine that you've got a number that's got nothing to do with dates, it's just a positive integer. Your task is to print a message if that number is greater than or equals 30, another one if it's greater than or equals 60, and one more message for each time it is divisible by 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the type `LocalTime` instead. If you have `DateTime` as input then please convert it using the method `toLocalTime()` (with same time and chronology and timezone).

```
LocalTime start = new LocalTime(13, 46);
LocalTime end = new LocalTime(18, 46);
LocalTime current = start;

for (int i = 0; current.isBefore(end); i++) {
    // code your print action here
    current = current.plusMinutes((i < 2) ? 30 : 60);
}
```

Then you get an action for following times:

```
13:46
14:16
14:46
15:46
16:46
17:46
```